# Register nib name for tableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
if (tableView ==tableview1) 
{
    ContactCustom *cell1=(ContactCustom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];        
    if (cell1 == nil) 
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCustom" owner:self options:nil];
        cell1 = contactCustom;
    }
}
```

How to register nib name in `viewDidLoad` method before calling `cellForRowAtIndex` method?

Answer (score 36):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"cell" bundle:nil] 
   forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, after struggling with the same issue for hours and trying everything else mentioned this finally fixed my issue. After doing this you can remove the "if" statement from the cellForRowAtIndex method

Comment: how can you set the owner?

Answer (score 3):

Apple provided register nib method for UITableView after IOS 5 
Please check class reference 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Ex:

```
     In view did load you can register nib for UITableView like below
     [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"identifienName"];

      In cellForRowAtIndexPath
      cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifienName"];
```

Comment: getting error.How to change this code for tableView with customCell

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x9b64220> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contactCustom.

Comment: When registering xib, no need to check if cell is nil !

Answer (score 3):

For Swift

```
tableViewSubCategory.register(UINib(nibName: "", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    [_tbl_setpaper registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SetPaperCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

Just put oneline in your viewdidload, you must have table outlet,cell identifier,cell class.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://mrmaksimize.com/Custom-UITableViewCell-With-NIB/

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"EXCustomCell"
                             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
             forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseID"];
    }
```

Later in code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseID";
    EXCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.cellItemImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_428_podium"]];
    [cell.cellItemLabel setText = @"Mr Burns."];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
if (tableView ==tableview1) 
{
    ContactCustom *cell1=(ContactCustom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];        
    if (cell1 == nil) 
    {
        cell1 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check that xib is properly connected with class and Identifier is proper set in xib
and use below code
cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: it should be cell in Identifier property in ContactCustom class

Answer (score 0):

```
// First of all Declare an IBOutlet for your customCell in Your View Controller
IBOutlet ScoreCell *scoreCell;
// Synthesize it.
// Assign your view controller class to File Owner of your custom cell (Eg. File Owner of ScoreCell.xib)
// Then Assign Reference Outlet of ScoreCell.xib with Object 'scoreCell'
// Finally Create your custom Cell as follow :

ScoreCell *cell = (ScoreCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Registers a nib object containing a cell with the table view under a specified identifier.

```
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
Parameters
```

**nib**
A nib object that specifies the nib file to use to create the cell. This parameter cannot be nil.
**identifier**
The reuse identifier for the cell. This parameter must not be nil and must not be an empty string.

This [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) can help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

> UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Custom_cellTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
>      [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Custom_cellTableViewCell"];

This code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

***For OBJECTIVE-C***

```
//First TableView Declaration:
self.customTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];

//Then Nib Registration Registration:
[self.customTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil]  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCellIdentifier"];

//Then Adding Tableview to self.view
[self.view addSubview: _customTableView];
```