# UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues

Tags: ios, uitableview

I try to implement slide menu

For Reference use this [site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2f700d/create-leftrightboth-slider-menus-in-your-app-with-objecti/).

For some reason my app is failing  when click on left side or right side itembar app will be crash and crash report is display below.

Here My Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     menu = @[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", @"seven", @"eight", @"nine"];

self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.view.layer.borderWidth = .6;
    self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;

    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; // app crash here

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Output:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3694.4.18/UITableView.m:7732
2017-12-22 15:15:00.178615+0530 slideMenu[5310:202050] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier one - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e7f1cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001107e1f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e84362 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000110286089 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000111b48968 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:] + 890
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000111b485ba -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 89
    6   slideMenu                           0x000000010febd7a5 -[NavigationViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 181
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000111b63ef0 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 727
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000111b644ab -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000111b2a870 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2892
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000111b4bde9 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000111ad9551 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1331
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000117d4a4ba -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000117d4e5a9 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000117cd71cd _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 365
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000117d02ae4 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000111a04f4a _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 167
    17  UIKit                               0x000000011235c960 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6894
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e222b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ec1d31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e06c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e061ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e05a89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011760f9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000111a0ad30 UIApplicationMain + 159
    25  slideMenu                           0x000000010febd9df main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114ee1d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to register your tableViewCell for xib in viewDidLoad @Gangani Roshan see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360694/register-nib-name-for-tableview

Comment: `'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier one - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard` That's the important part of your message. I don't think that you want to do `NSString *cellIdentifier = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. That's not the identifier you want.

Comment: You have not registered your Table view cell. Write this in viewDidLoad : [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"]; with the same reuse identifier you provide in cell for index. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gangani Roshan in cell identifier you have to pass cell identifier name like "SidemenuCell" may be it your cell class name or what you have define in your XIB

Comment: @Larme i would add static cell and also provide identifier name of array define above.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu why add vewDidLoad in line?

Comment: You have 9 totally different cells that don't look alike? Really? Stop using SWReveal. Do not care about the Side Menu. Open a new project, and understand how UITableView work.

Comment: @Larme thankls for advice i will try.

Answer (score 0):

To dequeue a specific cell you must first register the table with it like this in viewDidLoad:

```
   UINib *nib1 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"moreTableViewCell" bundle:nil];

   [self.tableView registerNib:nib1 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"firstCell"];
```

So here I should have .h,.m,.xib class in project named moreTableViewCell:

So, in cellforRow it's valid to do this:

```
 moreTableViewCell *cell =[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstCell"];
```

These two lines are the main reason for the crash

```
 NSString *cellIdentifier = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; // app crash here
```

You want to dequeue a cell from the tableview that you hadn't registered previously.

Comment: say deeply i can't understand what are you saying.

Comment: yes but you refer link i have given in post? i try from that.